# lost phone and password Apple ID

Tags: iphone

I have used iPhone 6s before it was stolen in December 2016. I bought an iPhone 7 Plus but cannot login into my old account. I already tried to sign in but it failed. It seems that the password has changed. I tried all my password possibilities but it still will not work. 
I need to login to my Apple ID because all my applications are linked with the old iPhone.
I had also tried to enter my credit card number but still not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that you have the correct email address for the Apple ID, you could try to reset the password using the following link: [appleid.apple.com](https://appleid.apple.com/)

The website will ask for your birthday and possibly also your security questions.

If you don't know the answer to your security questions anymore, you can contact Apple Care. The phone number for Apple Care in your country is listen on this page from Apple: [Apple Care phone numbers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201232)